# Docker now giving an error after updating

Tags: docker

After using Docker for almost two months, today I got the following error:

> C:\Users\dell>docker --version
>   Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
>
> C:\Users\dell>docker ps -a
>   error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/containers/json?all=1:
>   open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker
>   client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate
>   that the docker daemon is not running.

Yes, the daemon is running, or at least it is shown as running under Services. I use it only with a local container and do not do anything remote.

Any suggestions on how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have had the same issue today and the only way for me to fix it was by reinstalling Docker (uninstall and install latest stable version)...

Now docker info runs OK and my solution builds again.

I hope it helps,

Juan

Note: it shouldn't have happened at all, I've lost at least one hour trying to figure out what and why it crashed...

Answer (score 0):

Is Hyper-V running? You will get this error if Hyper-V closes down. Docker for Windows will still be "running", but the daemon will not work.